# Аудит работы php

Tags: php

Например, имеется база данных. Пользователи вносят в нее информацию. Как сделать так, чтоб была политика аудита? Какой пользователь, что и когда внес? Чисто на БД ясно: добавить к полю таблицы ИД пользователя. А как осуществить программно? Отталкиваться от сессии? Или что-нибудь другое?

Answer (score 2):

Что это за пользователи, которые информацию в БД вносят ? Если зарегистрированные, то проблемы не вижу вообще - авторизация пользователя изначально подразумевает хранение информации о нем, то есть, скрипт, добавляющий информацию, может и user_id вытащить - из сессии, базы, кукис.. не знаю уж, как там у Вас все организовано.

Если это неавторизованные пользователи со стороны, то это беда. Какой ID в таком случае предполагается хранить ? Кого Вы собираетесь идентифицировать ? В крайнем случае, можно хранить в базе IP, но они далеко не всегда статические.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно два варианта рассмотреть.
**Пользователи зарегистрированы.**
Нужно завести табличку в которой будут перечислены возможные операции с БД, например,
Создание записи, Удаление, Редактирование. Далее записывать в отдельную таблицу БД, информацию о пользователе - его id, дату, id действия.
Если пользователи **не зарегистрированы** процедура остается такая же, однако, встает вопрос вычисления уникальности посетителя. Для этого есть простое решение берется информация о посетителе(ip, браузер, разрешение экрана, ось - чем больше тем лучше, в интернете есть котовое решение на js, учитывающее более 100-ни параметров), записывается в строку, для которой получают хэш с помощью md5() и его записывают в базу. Это самый просто способ персонализировать незарегистрированного пользователя.